# How to plot a relief in 3D in scilab but color it according to another matrix stating absence/presence of animals

Tags: matrix, surf, scilab, colormap

I have two matrices of equal size and resolution that I loaded on scilab. The first stores the elevation of my terrain (let's call it DTM), and the second stores a value per cell between 0 and 1 symbolizing presence and density of a certain animal (let's call it PRES).

I want to plot DTM as a 3D surface and color that surface using PRES. I used the command surf() to plot DTM, but I have spent all day trying to figure out how to use PRES to color it. Can anyone help me with this task?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution:

```
surf(DTM,PRES);
```

I thought it wasn't working before because the PRES matrix was wrong.